# XSLT - adding attribute dynamically in grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <section>
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
        <p id="main">gg</p>
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

my task is group the above content based on `id="para1"` and `id='para2'` attributes and add a section to each group. My desired output is

```
<doc>
    <section>
        <p id="main">aa</p>
        <p id="main">bb</p>
        <p id="main">cc</p>
    </section>
    <section  type="First para">
        <p id="para1">dd</p>
        <p id="main">ee</p>
        <p id="main">ff</p>
        <p id="main">gg</p>
    </section>
    <section type="Second para">
        <p id="para2">hh</p>
        <p id="main">ii</p>
        <p id="main">jj</p>
    </section>
    <section  type="First para">
        <p id="para1">xx</p>
        <p id="main">yy</p>
        <p id="main">zz</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

The xsl to do this task is follows,

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(@id, 'para')]">
            <section type="?">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </section>      
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
```

This xsl will do the job but can you suggest a way that how can I add `type` attribute value of the adding `<section>` node based on the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[starts-with(@id, 'para')]">
        <section>
            <xsl:if test="current-group()[1][not(@id='main')]">
                <xsl:attribute name="type" select="current-group()[1]/@id"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </section>      
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
    <section>
      <p id="main">aa</p>
      <p id="main">bb</p>
      <p id="main">cc</p>
   </section>
    <section type="para1">
      <p id="para1">dd</p>
      <p id="main">ee</p>
      <p id="main">ff</p>
      <p id="main">gg</p>
   </section>
    <section type="para2">
      <p id="para2">hh</p>
      <p id="main">ii</p>
      <p id="main">jj</p>
   </section>
    <section type="para1">
      <p id="para1">xx</p>
      <p id="main">yy</p>
      <p id="main">zz</p>
   </section>
</doc>
```

---

Transforming "para1" and "para2" into "First para" and "Second para" respectively may be more complicated. It would help knowing all possible combinations that can appear. If it's always in the format of "paraN", then you could use:

```
<xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:number value="substring-after(current-group()[1]/@id, 'para')" format="Ww" ordinal="yes"/>
    <xsl:text> para</xsl:text>
</xsl:attribute>
```

to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
    <section>
      <p id="main">aa</p>
      <p id="main">bb</p>
      <p id="main">cc</p>
   </section>
    <section type="First para">
      <p id="para1">dd</p>
      <p id="main">ee</p>
      <p id="main">ff</p>
      <p id="main">gg</p>
   </section>
    <section type="Second para">
      <p id="para2">hh</p>
      <p id="main">ii</p>
      <p id="main">jj</p>
   </section>
    <section type="First para">
      <p id="para1">xx</p>
      <p id="main">yy</p>
      <p id="main">zz</p>
   </section>
</doc>
```

Comment: Inside the `for-each-group` the context node is the first item in each group so you could shorten `<xsl:if test="current-group()[1][not(@id='main')]">` to `<xsl:if test="not(@id='main')">` and `<xsl:attribute name="type" select="current-group()[1]/@id"/>` to `<xsl:attribute name="type" select="@id"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am sure you are correct, but I cannot find confirmation in the specs. All it says is that the *initial item* is the *context item* **for the purposes of sorting**.

Comment: The section on `for-each-group` defines "For each group, the item within the group that is first in population order is known as the initial item of the group." and then later says "The sequence constructor contained in the xsl:for-each-group element is evaluated once for each of the groups, in processing order. ... Within the sequence constructor, the context item is the initial item of the relevant group ..."

Comment: @MartinHonnen I see. If you hadn't pointed to it now, I'd never understood it to mean what you said in your first comment. I will leave my answer as is, since I believe anyone who reads this will benefit more by following this discussion. And thank you for clarifying.